# Why I get "invalid instruction operands" on line 41? MASM 32

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
.686p 
.xmm
.model flat,c
.stack  4096


; include C libraries
includelib      msvcrtd
includelib      oldnames
includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib


; imported functions
extrn   printf:near


.data ; initialized global vars
IntegerFormat   db  "The result is: %d",0dh,0ah,0
GlobWord      db "This is just a test",0dh,0ah,0
GlobFstC      dd "i"
GlobSecC      db "g"

.code
        
public  main

main proc
xor     eax, eax
xor     ecx, ecx
xor     ebx, ebx
mov     ecx, -1
mov     ebx, offset GlobWord

SwitchChars:
    inc     ecx
    movsx   eax, byte ptr [ebx + ecx]
    cmp     eax, 0
    je  Exit
    cmp     eax, GlobFstC
    jne     SwitchChars
    mov     byte ptr [ebx + ecx], GlobSecC 
    jmp     SwitchChars

Exit:
    movsx   eax, GlobWord
    push    eax    
    push    offset IntegerFormat
    call    printf  ; call printf(IntegerFormat, 3)
    add     esp, 8 
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
    main endp
    end
```

the code is for switching first char in the second one in the string, error A2070 "invalid instruction operands" on the line "mov     byte ptr [ebx + ecx], GlobSecC"

any suggestions to fix / better way to go through String in masm 32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two memory operands in an x86 instruction (except for certain special purpose instructions).  To fix the code, first load `GlobSecC` into a register, then store that register into `[ebx + ecx]`.

```
movzx edx, GlobSecC
mov [ebx + ecx], dl
```